# How to edit a file with one command?

Tags: linux, bash, configuration

i have a question:

How can i edit a file (e.g. php.ini) without opening it with editor? I can only use one command via SSH/SOAP so i tried to remove the file and write it new but this is slow and doesn't work well.

for example i want to edit this `post_max_size = 8M` to `post_max_size = 32M` with one single command. Is that possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Stream edit - also known as "sed" is your friend.

```
sed 's/post_max_size = 8M/post_max_size = 32M/' infile > outfile

sed -i 's/post_max_size = 8M/post_max_size = 32M/' inplace_file
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's perfect for the script.

Comment: If using a these as part of an ssh command, be sure to add another layer of quotes/escapes around the quotes/escapes/redirects/etc that you want interpreted by the remote shell (e.g. `ssh user@computer "sed 's/post_max_size = 8M/post_max_size = 32M/' infile > outfile"`).

Answer (score 0):

use perl one liner...feel free to change the below line of course to customize it and make it more selective.

```
perl -p -i -e 's/8M/32M/g' file_name
```

Answer (score 0):

You definitely could also use GNU [ed](http://www.gnu.org/software/ed/).

However, I believe that you should use some version control system (like `git`). Then you could edit it (on your local Linux laptop), and transmit it appropriately (e.g. `git commit` + `git push` on the local laptop, and `git pull` on the remote host).